# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException While calling rest post call

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

This is my client side code

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForObject(appConfig.getRestUrl(),processFiles, ResponseEntity.class);
```

And this is my Rest controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/processfiles/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addProcessFiles(@RequestBody List<ProcessFiles> processFiles) {
    try {
        processFilesDao.save(processFiles);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failure occured at server side");
    }
```

The same code works if I use String.class as return type in post call.But not with Response entity class. What am I doing wrong, if I need client also the same response entity

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@15778da9; line: 1, column: 15]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
>       at com.mmx.ta2s3.serviceImpl.Ta2S3ServiceImpl.callRestService(Ta2S3ServiceImpl.java:170)
>       at com.mmx.ta2s3.Ta2S3Application.task(Ta2S3Application.java:48)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>       at com.mmx.ta2s3.Ta2S3Application.main(Ta2S3Application.java:38)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@15778da9; line: 1, column: 15]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3528)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2686)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:878)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:241)
>       ... 31 more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/processfiles/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addProcessFiles(@RequestBody List<ProcessFiles> processFiles) {
try {
    processFilesDao.save(processFiles);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Failure occured at server side", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Still the same result bro!

Comment: try this `return new ResponseEntity<>("true", HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: Following error:JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no boolean/Boolean-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from boolean value (true); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no boolean/Boolean-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from boolean value (true)

Comment: What about sending body empty?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it cannot convert "Success" String to ResponseEntity, use string generic type instead :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/processfiles/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> addProcessFiles(@RequestBody List<ProcessFiles> processFiles) {
```